# Edit browser's history API with Angular router

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have an application where we construct a series of temporary data points all with an ID of 0. I reference all these points individually by keying them as 01, 02, 03, etc. My route is `/details/:id`. If a user saves one of these data points our API creates a real ID. So the process looks something like this to the user:

Go to temp item at `/details/0123`

Save changes to item 0123.

Receive the new item in the response with an id of 456.

Angular reroutes to `/details/456` and the user doesnt notice the transition unless they were paying attention to the URL.

However, if a user hits the Back Button on their browser they will route to `/details/0123`.

**Question:** Can I edit the browser history via the Angular router (or some other reliable means) to prevent navigating to `/details/0123`?

Comment: So just to make things a bit more clear, what should happen when they press back button on the browser?

Comment: @VinodBhavnani they should not be directed to `/details/0123` because that temp data point now exists as ID `456`. They should either go to the page before they went to `/details/0123` or to `/details/456` (I dont know which is the most plausible or aesthetically pleasing)

Comment: Can't you listen to the window popstate event?

Comment: So on that you could prevent default and use router.navigate to any component you like?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can replace the route `/details/0123` with the route `/details/456` in the browser history by adding `replaceUrl: true` in the `NavigationExtras`.

Example:

`this.router.navigate(['/details/456'], { replaceUrl: true });`

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is use Angular's Location and subscribe to the popstate. Something like this:

```
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs/Subscription';

export class ABC implements OnDestroy {
location: Location;
private subscription: Subscription;

      constructor(location: Location, router: Router) {
        this.subscription = location.subscribe(val => this.router.navigate(/*anywhere*/)
      }
      ngOnDestroy(){
          this.subscription.unsubscribe() //Make sure you do this :)
      }
}
```

I think that should work for you. Let me know.